# PJAX with PHP - Not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pjax

I'm currently trying to implement PJAX for selective content loads.

It's a portfolio site and I want to reload the video player page when any thumbnail is clicked on  `index.php`.

The page can be found [here](http://www.jameshenry.info/test/)

I have a `<div>` element called `content` and I want any of the `<a>` elements (within `content`) to PJAX in the corresponding video page (into the `content` element)

My Javascript is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var $container = $('#thumbnail-array');

                $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
                    $container.masonry({
                        itemSelector: '.video-thumbnail',
                        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
                        gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
                        percentPosition: true
                    });
                });

            jQuery('.mobilemenu').click(function(e) {
                jQuery(this).toggleClass('is-active');
                jQuery('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('active');

                var delay = 100;
                    $('.linkitem').each(function(i, e) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    $(e).toggleClass('animate');
                    }, i * delay);
                });

                if(jQuery('.mobile-nav').hasClass('active')) {
                    $('body').on('touchmove', false);
                } else  {
                    $('body').off('touchmove', false);
                }
                });

                BackgroundCheck.init({
                    targets: '.name logo, .rightnav, .mobilemenu mobilemenu--htx'
            });

            $(".fittext").fitText(1.5);
            $(".fittext2").fitText(1.3, { minFontSize: '15px', maxFontSize: '20px' });

            $('.content a').pjax();

            $('.overlay').hover(function(){
                $(this).parent().find('video').get(0).play();
                }, function() {
                    var video = $(this).parent().find('video').get(0);
                    video.pause();
                    video.currentTime = 0;
                });
            });
            $(window).bind("load", function() {
            $.getScript('js/social.js', function() {});
            });
        </script>
```

I'm not getting any errors or feedback related to PJAX, just the usual behaviour of a full page load.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your selector has some mistakes. And your `div` has a `class` not an `id` It should be :

```
$('.content a').pjax();
```

Comment: If you can check your console, you will see an element not found error.

Comment: I've corrected the ID/class mismatch in the code, but still no dice! The error also seems to be thrown up by a different script, namely `backgroundcheck.js` - could this be affecting the PJAX call?

Comment: If you have any js error on your pages, your other js code may not work properly. Kindly provide complete js code to get a relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a javascript error with regards to my use of another script, BackgroundCheck.JS - See the revised javascript below!:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var $container = $('#thumbnail-array');

            $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
                $container.masonry({
                    itemSelector: '.video-thumbnail',
                    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
                    gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
                    percentPosition: true
                });
            });

        jQuery('.mobilemenu').click(function(e) {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('is-active');
            jQuery('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('active');

            var delay = 100;
                $('.linkitem').each(function(i, e) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                $(e).toggleClass('animate');
                }, i * delay);
            });

            if(jQuery('.mobile-nav').hasClass('active')) {
                $('body').on('touchmove', false);
            } else  {
                $('body').off('touchmove', false);
            }
            });


        $(".fittext").fitText(1.5);
        $(".fittext2").fitText(1.3, { minFontSize: '15px', maxFontSize: '20px' });

        $('.content a').pjax();

        $('.overlay').hover(function(){
            $(this).parent().find('video').get(0).play();
            }, function() {
                var video = $(this).parent().find('video').get(0);
                video.pause();
                video.currentTime = 0;
            });
        });
        $(window).bind("load", function() {
        $.getScript('js/social.js', function() {});
        });

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            BackgroundCheck.init({
                targets: '.name, .logo, .desktop-nav, .right-nav, .mobilemenu span, .mobilemenu span:before, .mobilemenu span:after, .mobilemenu--htx'
            });
        });

    </script>
```

I'm still having a few issues, but at least I can now see PJAX pushing the content.